# How can you get more accurate results of lng and lat

Tags: javascript, html, css, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am using a MapBox and when user clicks on a map you get lng lat which is not very accurate, I clicked in United Kindom but when I checked in google maps that values pointed me in the middle of the sea.

How can this be solved? I need it to be very accurate, I have heard that it needs position absolute, which I did and gave me the same result.

```
        <div id="right" class="map">

            <div id='map' class="map" style='width: 100%; height: 100%;'></div>
                                <pre id='info'></pre>
            <script>
            mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibGl2ZS1vbGRoYW0iLCJhIjoiY2ozbXk5ZDJ4MDAwYjMybzFsdnZwNXlmbyJ9.VGDuuC92nvPbJo-qvhryQg';
            var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'map',
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v10',
                        center: [-1.77, 52.73],
                        zoom: 3

            });
                        map.on('click', function(e) {
                        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML =
                        JSON.stringify(e.point) + JSON.stringify(e.lngLat);
});
            </script>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

`[-1.77, 52.73]` is in the middle of the sea, but `[52.73, -1.77]` is [in the UK](https://www.google.com/maps/place/52%C2%B043'48.0%22N+1%C2%B046'12.0%22W/@52.7231601,-1.949465,10.75z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d52.73!4d-1.77?hl=en). Lat and Lng are the other way round.

Comment: I use this JSON.stringify(e.lngLat); however I cannot swap them around as it gives me back undefined